# Encrypted Excel File ExcelWriter Issue

Tags: python

I've Excel file with ecrypted when I try to open exceel sheet. I couldnt created the new sheet, but it does not give any error. Where is my problem ?

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.file_name = io.BytesIO()
    
        with open('private\cabc.xlsx', 'rb') as file:
        office_file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(file)
        office_file.load_key(password='password')
        office_file.decrypt(self.file_name)
        self.wb = load_workbook(filename=self.file_name)

         print('created new excel sheet')
         writer = pd.ExcelWriter(self.file_name, engine='openpyxl', mode='a')

         # writer.self.wb = self.wb
         title = ['a','b']
         df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=title)
         df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=self.today)
         writer.close()
```

Comment: You aren't using `office_file` anywhere.  What is `file_name` supposed to be doing?  Where do add a new sheet?

Comment: why should i use office_file ?

Comment: I updated question but I couldnt change sheet

Comment: Where did `load_workbook` come from?  You have called your variable `self.file_name`, but it is NOT a file name.  It is an in-memory file object that contains the bytes of the decrypted workbook.